# Zend framework: How to detect environment(dev/prod) in code

Tags: php, debugging, email, zend-framework

I use `Zend_Mail` component in my application for sending mails via SMTP protocol.

And I want to persist my messages to files when I'm in `development` environment(accordingly to application.ini).

How can I detect in my controller action whether it is development or `production`/`staging` environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `Zend_Application` and the ini settings load correctly (meaning the enviroment variable is setup correctly in your .htaccess file), then just use the `APPLICATION_ENV` constant.

That will match whatever application.ini setting is used (because that's what determines the section).

Answer (score 1):

Or if managing different .htaccess files is too much hassle (or if you are not using Zend_Application), I sometimes parse the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to get the domain name then work out your environment from there.